# js: x++ behavior differs on assignment?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused why I get different results when simply incrementing a variable in javascript.

First, the following obviously makes sense:

```
x = 0
x++
x++
// x == 2
```

But this doesn't make sense (not that I would actually use this in real code):

```
x = 0
x = x++
x = x++
// x == 0
```

How are these operations not practically the same? / why am I getting different final results?

Comment: Because your setting x to itself, and then incrementing..  you maybe wanted `++x` instead.

Comment: @Keith actually its reading it into a temp, then incrementing, then assigning.

Comment: this is because [OperatorPrecedence] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: @ParitoshMahale thanks. It looks like postfix increment has a higher precedence than assignment, like pretty much every other operator and whatnot. Shouldn't this mean that my x variable would be incremented then assigned to itself still?

Comment: this means x get assign first with value 0 to new variable which is also x unfortunately. new x get's value of 0 then old x's value get increment but also get override by new x